# Enter Event in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, mobile

I want to write a basic application in which when the User press enter after providing the User Name and Password certain action has to take place. I have attached javascript with the textbox.

Although this works well with traditional browser it is not working in BlackBerry.

Any Idea how I can get this working?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press Enter key it does not return 13 instead it returns so unless you are developing particularly for BlackBerry using its support apps let it go and yes it will work fine for Iphone and Android.

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing I would do:

- [check if JavaScript is enabled on device](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800878/852943/How_To_-_Determine_if_JavaScript_is_enabled_on_a_device.html?nodeid=1067186&vernum=0)
- [check if JavaScript is compliant with Blackberry Browser](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800878/852943/What_Is_-_BlackBerry_Browser_JavaScript_Support.html?nodeid=852416&vernum=0)